# I need a way to display JSON and XML in a control in ASP.NET webform

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, xml, formatting

So I am making a call to a Web API webservice using the WebClient class.
My response can be either XML or JSON. Is there a control I can use
that will nicely format the response or will I need to write routines
to put in the breaks where needed? Right now I am just assigning
the response string to an asp literal. But it doesn't look very
good with it as one continuous string like this:
{"RateID":"USCA-SDSD-TOU5-0000","RateName":"TOU-A-2","RateType":"Time of use","Sector":"Commercial Industrial and Agricultural","API_Url":"RateAPI.com","RatePlan_Url":"http://regarchive.sdge.com/tm2/pdf/ELEC_ELEC-SCHEDS_TOU-A2.pdf","Price":0.1040900,"Unit":"kWh"}

It would be nice if there is a control that recognizes JSON and puts breaks after the commas or formats the XML as it should as well. If it did some color coding of different elements that would be gravy on top. If I just need to start writing code to do the formatting myself just let me know. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Here is a JavaScript library that performs code beautification: https://github.com/beautify-web/js-beautify

Comment: Are you sure you want to display the raw JSON or XML to the user? Are you trying to use webforms to respond with JSON or XML?

Comment: Hello Hans, yes I want to display the raw JSON and XML because the audience is techie. Its a technical utility that I am building. Its to verify the API is working correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you could toss the string as a converted object into one of MANY data objects in .net

once you "get" the data into a .net data object, then you really don't need code to render.

Drag + drop a gridview on the web form.

Drag + drop a DetailsView onto the web form.

Now, our code to display the data is this:

```
Sub MyFill()

    Dim strExtra As String

    strExtra = "{MyCoolRows: [" & TextBox1.Text & "]}"
    Dim MyTable As New DataSet

    MyTable = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of DataSet)(strExtra)

    GridView1.DataSource = MyTable
    GridView1.DataBind()

    DetailsView1.DataSource = MyTable
    DetailsView1.DataBind()

End Sub
```

Now I put both a gridview, and a details view onto the page. I think the details view works rather nice.

The result of the above WEE bit of code is thus this:

[image]

Just looking at above - I think a gridview is too wide.

But, for next to none code, the details view without any setup or defaults does not all bad of a job here.

And the SAME two objects can render xml quite nice and easy also.

(dataset has a loadxml - so in place of the newtonsoft, you can use the loadxml of the dataset object - and then again shove that right into the Details view object.

So, the code is not much - eg this (above vb as c#)

```
public void MyFill()
{
string strExtra;

strExtra = "{MyCoolRows: [" + TextBox1.Text + "]}";
DataSet MyTable = new DataSet();

MyTable = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DataSet>(strExtra);

GridView1.DataSource = MyTable;
GridView1.DataBind();

DetailsView1.DataSource = MyTable;
DetailsView1.DataBind();
}
```

Comment: Thank you Albert but I think you misunderstood what I was asking for. I wanted to keep the true Json and XML formatting just making it look nicer with proper stacking and indentation. I was able to figure it out using Newtonsoft.JValue.Parse for the Json and XDocument.Parse for the XML and converting back out to a string. My only issue now is trying to color code it. I am looking at a jquery plug-in called pretty-print-json. Hopefully I can get it working for me.

Comment: Ah, ok - data bound controls certainly can achieve a layout (and with very little code)- but it a end user presentation kind of thing - not the actual json string display (or perhaps xml display).